# Обновление view с переданными данными

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Имеется `tabBar` с двумя вкладками. На первой вкладке `view` со списком пользователей. При нажатии на пользователя открывается вторая вкладка с `view` на котором карточка пользователя. Я передаю в тот контроллер user'а и делаю `profileView.viewDidLoad()`. Далее уже отслеживаю поведение и вот что получается:

```
Readу to send ----- User ID: 7
viewDidLoad ----- User ID: 7
viewDidLoad ----- User ID: 7
viewDidLoad ----- User ID: 1
viewWillAppear ----- User ID: 1
```

Почему `viewDidLoad` вызывает трижды и почему меняется ID пользователя на значение по умолчанию?
Если этот метод не подходит, то какой использовать для обновления `view`?

UPDATE

Задача такая: Если я тыкаю на юзера, то должна открыться вторая вкладка таббара и в ней быть данные того юзера, на которого тыкнул.
Если я делаю так, то у меня открывается вьха с профилем юзера по умолчанию. А этот никак не передаётся

```
func showUserProfile(sender: User.Identifier) {
        let profileView = ProfileViewController()
        guard let user = DataProviders.shared.usersDataProvider.user(with: sender) else { return }
        tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
        profileView.receivedUser = user
        navigationController?.pushViewController(profileView, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: `profileView.viewDidLoad()` - если вызываете этот метод напрямую, то так не делается

Comment: Также неплохо бы было представить в виде кода минимальный пример для воспроизведения

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас, например какая-то таблица, можно использовать метод reloadData.

Если у вас просто view с текстом и картинкам, тогда используйте уведомления (notification) или тригеры.